# Angular, material form only say field is required after submit attempt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I a building my apps login form with angular-material and  am trying to use it a bit differently than the examples on their page. I just want the required fields to only yell at me if the user tries to submit without filling a field out. Maybe disable the button too? Regardless, if the user only fills one field out and presses enter, I would like it to show that "this is required". Right now it just shows it all the time until you fill it out

Here is what I have : https://jsfiddle.net/5b1tsm2a/6/

I am trying the code from their example page like so -

```
  <form ng-submit="authenticate()" name="loginForm">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input name="name" reauired ng-model="loginInfo.username">
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.description.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input name="password" reauired type="password" ng-model="loginInfo.password">
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.description.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-button ng-click="authenticate()" class="md-primary btn btn-primary">Login</md-button>
    </form>
```

So I'm using the required logic with the ng-messages below it. I would only like that to show if they have tried to submit without filling out anything. Thanks!

Comment: Suggested documentation for [forms in angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form).  Also there are typos "reauired".

Answer (score 5):

Update your code as below :

```
<form ng-submit="authenticate()" name="loginForm">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input name="username" ng-model="loginInfo.username" required/>
            <div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" ng-if='loginForm.username.$dirty'>
                <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="loginInfo.password" required/>
            <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" ng-if='loginForm.password.$dirty'>
                <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button type="submit" class="md-primary btn btn-primary">Login</md-button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks! is there any way to have it show both are required if you fill out nothing - it seems to just say the top (name) is required only if you leave both blank.

Comment: When u place "required" attribute in multiple input fields, then required messages will appear in sequence as the fields occur. This is the default behavior. Yes, u can change. Use yr custom validation with help of angular.  check this : http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Comment: Did this work?  I would've thought you'd need to include a novalidate attribute on the form and use loginForm.$submitted rather than checking if each field is dirty?